# Regular Expression Match for Tags

Tags: c#, regex, tags

I need to use C# to write a Regular Expression for tags, here is the requirement:

1. Tags are optional;
2. Maximum 9 tags;
3. no duplicated tags;
4. Maximum 30 characters for each tag;
5. Each tag should only contain reasonable characters (how to define?, I'm now using `[\w-]`);
6. Tags are separated by `,` (with or without one whitespace after the comma are optional);
7. The ending `,` (with or without one whitespace) is also legal.

I have already had this:

```
^(|[\w-]{1,30}(,\s?[\w-]{1,30}){0,8}(,\s?)?)$
```

I find it's difficult to meet all the rules. especially rule 3.

**EDIT:**

1. Updated rule 5, rule 6;
2. Applied rule 7.

Comment: I don't think requirement 3 is even possible with just regular expressions. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Instead of using regex, I would have split the string by `,` and process the "tags" one-by-one (e.g. trim spaces, validate allowed chars, lower case), sort it and get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it without Regex:

```
public static bool TryGetTags(string tagsInput, out string[] tags)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\w_-]+$");

    tags = tagsInput.Split(',')  // Rule 6
                    .Select(tag => tag.Trim())
                    .ToArray();

    if (tags.Last() == "")
        tags = tags.Take(tags.Length - 1).ToArray();  // Rule 7

    if (tags.Any(tag => tag == ""))  // (no empty tag allowed except last one)
        return false;

    if (tags.Length > 9)
        return false;  // Rule 2

    if (tags.Any(tag => tag.Length > 30))
        return false;  // Rule 4

    if (tags.Distinct().Count() != tags.Length)
        return false;  // Rule 3

    if (tags.Any(tag => !regex.IsMatch(tag)))
        return false;  // Rule 5

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Without regex? What is `regex` then?

Comment: I finally gave up the regex for checking the duplicated tags.  For the other rules, I"m still using regex.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, I gave up the regex for checking the duplicated tags (rule 3). I'm still using regex for other rules.

```
    public static bool CheckTags(string tags)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(tags, @"^(|[\w-]{1,30}(,\s?[\w-]{1,30}){0,8}(,\s?)?)$"))
            return false;

        // Step 1: Check duplicated tags
        // Step 1.1: Remove the whitespace first
        tags = Regex.Replace(tags, @"\s+", @"");
        string[] tagsArray = tags.Split(',');

        // Step 1.2: Check if duplicated items exist
        if (tagsArray.Distinct().Count() != tagsArray.Length)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

The following test cases passed:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckTagsTest()
    {
        // Whitespaces and commas only
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags("  \t \n \u1680"));
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(" , , , "));
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(",,,"));
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(",, ,"));

        // 10 tags
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(@"tag0,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7,tag8,tag9"));

        // Duplicated tags
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(@"tag0,tag0"));

        // A tag contains more than 30 characters
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123*"));

        // A tag contains invalid characters
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(@"tag!"));
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(@"tag*"));

        // Tag separator contains more than one whitespaces
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTags(@"tag1, tag2,  tag3"));

        // Normal tags
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags(@"tag1, tag2, tag3"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags(@"tag1,tag2, tag3"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags("tag1,tag2,\ttag3, tag4"));

        // Ending tag separator is allowed
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags("tag1,tag2,\ttag3, tag4,"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags("tag1,tag2,\ttag3, tag4, "));

        // A tag contains 30 characters
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags(@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123"));

        // A tag contains '-'
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags(@"T-shirt"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags(@"-"));

        // A tag contains '_'
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags(@"T_shirt"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags(@"_"));

        // A tag contains chinese characters
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTags("\u4E2D"));
    }
```

The credit still goes Cedric Bignon.